# How to change a form value dynamically and submit during onclick

Tags: java, javascript, html, jakarta-ee

I am using onclick event in anchor tag. when i clcik the anchor, I am invoking a java script function where I change the value of one input element and submit the form. The value is changed but the form does not submit the value. Please help me on this. FYI that if i create an element and add in the form before submission, it works. Why is not working in the first scenario.

```
<form name="form" >    
    <input type="hidden" name="input" value="test"/>    
    <a onclick='testMethod("test")'>click </a>    
</form>
```

script used is

```
function testMethod(value)
{
    if(serviceName != null && jQuery('#form') != null)
    {
        document.forms['form'].getElementById('input').value = value;
        document.forms['form'].action = jQuery('#newAction').val();
        document.forms['form'].submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: post some codes. It'll be easier to solve

Comment: Check what is the value of `input` using `alert`

Comment: input is set proper. but, does not submit. but, if i create a element and append it to the form, i m gettin data in the controller. is there any restriction for this scenario?

Comment: `jQuery('#form')` will never be null - but it may be empty.

Comment: @sridhar You mean to say when you are calling `testMethod` page is not getting submitted?

Comment: I am changing the value of a form during onclick event. the value changes but not getting in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is you're trying to access the input by id when it doesn't have one set:

(Added `id` to form and `id` to input so we can select them easily):

```
<form name="form" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="input" id="input" value="test" />
    <a onclick='testMethod("test")' >click</a>
</form>
```

And the javascript to match (updating to use jQuery's selectors since you indicated you have jQuery support available):

```
function testMethod(value)
{
    var form = $('#form');
    if(serviceName != null && form.length)
    {
        $('#input').val(value);
        form.attr('action', $('#newAction').val());
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

You can also update your code such that you aren't including the binding to the onclick method in the DOM, but attaching to it directly in javascript:

Changing the `a` element to have an ID:

```
<form name="form" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="input" id="input" value="test" />
    <a id="submitLink">click</a>
</form>
```

The javascript could now look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submitLink').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#form');
        if(serviceName != null && form.length)
        {
            $('#input').val(value);
            form.attr('action', $('#newAction').val());
            form.submit();
        } 
    });
});
```