# Change hidden value and submit form with onclick for href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have multiple links acting as buttons, and each link has a different form with a hidden value storing the ID. The problem is that I'm using bootstrap and it's messing up the styling, and the only way around it seems to be having a single hidden value that will update with the selected ID once a link is clicked.

I currently have `<a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item list-group-item-default" onclick="parentNode.submit();">` as the link, and I've been looking around for a way to edit a value too. Unfortunately, it appears everyone seriously recommends not going down the javascript route and using jQuery instead, but I'm not quite sure how I'd link the two.

I've found [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/X8m7x/2/) which has a good example of how to do the jQuery to change values, though I could do with a bit of help putting it together, since I'm not sure if it's possible to use the jQuery code to submit the form as well, or if I should make a separate javascript function to run the jQuery then submit the form.

If there's actually nothing wrong with the javascript route, it looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216846/how-to-change-a-form-value-dynamically-and-submit-during-onclick) would do the job, just want to check first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, jQuery actually IS Javascript, it's merely an extention - if you're using jQuery, you are writing Javascript. jQuery just has become so popular that some people mix this up.

You can pass the form you want to be submitted as a parameter to the function like this:

```
function handleClickAction(formElement) {
    // change values
    formElement.submit();
}
```

With your given markup, you could call it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item list-group-item-default" onclick="handleClickAction(parentNode);">
```

Of course, you can add more parameters to the function call if you need to know what value to change and/or how.

In general, the solution you are using isn't very elegant and it's redundant, but if you want to go with inline code, this might be an appropriate way :)

Answer (score 1):

So do it in one line if you are doing inline events

```
onclick="document.formName.elementName.value='foo';this.form.submit();"
```

Comment: Thanks, just got it running, didn't think it'd work so easily haha, from what I gathered though, isn't this supposed to be bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's plugins rely on jQuery to function. That being the case, you'll see greater functionality (beyond just css styling) when you add jQuery to a bootstrap design. That being the case, here is a jQuery version which does what you are asking for:

NOTE: revised to answer subsequent questions in the comments. Now uses the index of the element clicked instead of the id, which is what the original post requested, since there is no id attribute assigned to the links.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#form_of_forms a.list-group-item').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#dynamic_form_id').val($(this).index()+1);
        $('#form_of_forms').submit();
    });
});
```

Additionally, replace `href="javascript:;"` with `href="#"` and remove the `onclick="..."` attribute from each link entirely.

Comment: Hey thanks, finding the input by searching for hidden inputs seems a little messy though, would I be able to change `$form.find('input[hidden]')` to `$('#input_id')`? That said, did you write it to work instantly out of the box if you have a list of `a` links with the class `list-group-item`, and a single hidden field?

Comment: yes. Since you didn't provide the id of the hidden field, I just relied on the fact that there is only one in the form. You can simplify the selectors if you have the id's already.

Comment: I only really know PHP so it's definitely useful seeing how it all works, it's pretty cool jQuery lets you do that. I'll try get it up and running now, just a question about using `closest('form')` though, is it like `parentNode`, or does it just find any form that's near, and therefore not a good idea if there's multiple forms?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble linking it up with the html, I tried putting it in head and underneath the links, it seems to create an empty div called `naptha_container` :P

Comment: No, it won't create any nodes. Perhaps you could post a link to what you are trying to do, or create a fiddle. As far as in head or under the links, you need to put this into a dom ready event or in your footer. Otherwise it will run before the elements it refers to actually exist.

Comment: Revised to include a dom ready event. As far as the container goes, perhaps bootstrap is adding one. Hard to tell exactly what you are doing without a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks, just wondering though since it's not very obvious (as in the script looks like it searches for the links and doesn't have any id), what needs to be done with the links? Anyway, got it up and running to an extent with the answer from Patches, since it's 99% PHP it'd be hard converting it into a fiddle so I'll just pass you the link to show you what I was trying to do. http://bit.ly/1htCs3A, user is admin, pw is test. I've currently got the hidden field as text, though I did edit that part of your code.